# How to Groupby one field value and Sortby another field in mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have my mongodb document structure as shown below:

```
{
        "_id" : NumberLong(366),
        "_class" : "com.cts.adpart.domain.DBData",
        "file" : "xyz",
        "meta" : {
                        "owner" : "user123",
        },
        "curFlag" : true
}
```

1. I have to check the document which is having `curFlag` true
2. One particular owner can handle `n` no of files, so I have to `GroupBy` owner and display the number of file that particular user is handling.
3. Finally based on the number of files each user is handling I have to display the user who is handling large no. of files.

For the above statement I have wrote the below code.

```
Map<String, Object> dbObjIdMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
dbObjIdMap.put("owner", "$meta.owner");
dbObjIdMap.put("curFlag", "$curFlag");
DBObject groupFields = new BasicDBObject( "_id", new BasicDBObject(dbObjIdMap));

groupFields.put("count", new BasicDBObject( "$sum", 1));
DBObject group = new BasicDBObject("$group", groupFields );
```

And it is giving me the output like below:

```
{ "_id" : { "owner" : "xyz@gmail.com", "curFlag" : true }, "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : { "owner" : "xyz@gmail.com", "curFlag" : false }, "count": 1 }
```

But I want to have only details of owner for whom `curFlag` is true and I have to display owner handling more number of files.

Can anyone help me with the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Translating your requirements into code, you get the following pipeline (mongo shell version):

```
// 1. Check for documents which have curFlag true
var match = { "$match": { "curFlag": true } };

// 2. GroupBy owner and display the number of files that particular user is handling
var group = {
    "$group": {
        "_id": "$meta.owner",
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }
};

// 3. Display the user who is handling large no. of files
var sort = { "$sort": { "count": -1 } },
    limit = { "$limit": 1 };

// Run pipeline
db.mycollection.aggregate([match, group, sort, limit])
```

**Java Implementation:**

```
public class JavaAggregation {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws UnknownHostException {

        MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient();
        DB db = mongo.getDB("test");

        DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("mycollection");

        // 1. Check for documents which have curFlag true
        DBObject match = new BasicDBObject("$match",
                            new BasicDBObject("curFlag", true)
                        );

        // 2. GroupBy owner and display the number of files per user
        DBObject groupFields = new BasicDBObject( "_id", "$meta.owner");
        groupFields.put("count", new BasicDBObject( "$sum", 1));
        DBObject group = new BasicDBObject("$group", groupFields);

        // 3. Display the user who is handling large no. of files
        DBObject sort = new BasicDBObject("$sort", 
                            new BasicDBObject("count", -1)
                        );
        DbObject limit = new BasicDBObject("$limit", 1);

        List<DBObject> pipeline = Arrays.asList(match, group, sort, limit);

        AggregationOutput output = coll.aggregate(pipeline);

        for (DBObject result : output.results()) {
            System.out.println(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Or with the v3 driver: AggregateIterable<Document> res = docs.aggregate(Arrays.asList(Aggregates.match(Filters.eq("curFlag", true)), Aggregates.sort(Sorts.orderBy(Sorts.descending("count"))), Aggregates.group("$meta.owner", Accumulators.sum("count", "1")), Aggregates.limit(1)));  // formatting up to the reader, as this is a comment and not an answer ;-)

Comment: Without knowing the data in your collection I can't tell exactly why it's returning only one user. Could you edit your question to show more sample documents with different users?